# Pandas: compare two separate dataframes, find intersection of one column, but use value in another column to determine which dataframe to keep?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames that look like this

```
df1
A     B   C
id1   X   0
id2   X   3
```

```
df2
A      B    C
id1    Y   -1
id4    Y    2
```

I want to find where column A intersects (in this case it's id1), then I want to compare the value in column C. I want to keep the data frame that has the lower value at C. So in this example, I would keep df2.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Comment: what is your expected output? 
Could more than one row coincide?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to check:

```
if df1['A'].map(dict(zip(df2['A'], df2['C']))).le(df1['C']).any():
    del df1
else:
    del df2
```